# JS download doesn't download entire file

Tags: javascript, html, download

I am trying to download a csv file with 3607 lines (1.0 Mb):

```js
const hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
const fileContent = `data:text/csv;charset=ansi,${res.data}`;

hiddenElement.href = fileContent;
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'file.csv';
hiddenElement.click();
```

The content at `res.data` is complete (as well as `fileContent`), but when i download the csv, the file only has 149 lines (4.4 Kb) instead of the original size.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can't you just redirect user to CSV file directly instead of this code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the api that i am using requires the file to be downloaded from a authenticated endpoint, if i redirect to a new page i will receive a 401 (unauthorized) error, and also i don't have control over this api

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that URLs cant have more than 2,048 characters

Comment: what change you had to make for above code to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and the same CSV download used to work earlier and download complete file.

had to change to the following:

```
const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' })
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement('a')
link.setAttribute('href', url)
```

Comment: Fixed it with providing the answer now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please consider taking the [tour] and reading [answer]. It might help you with some of the ideas, goals and concepts of StackOverflow which you seem to have missed.

Comment: On the other hand, cheers for taking my feedback and turning a should-be-comment post into an answer post. Add some explanation and you will find appreciation.